# When changing orientation of screen the app's UI dissapears

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In my android app, when I change the orientation from portrait to horizontal back to portrait the screen just goes blank. However when I tap on the screen the UI reappears. Any help would be appreciated

It happens to all the screens in my app. Here is an example of a screen that this happens to:

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBar
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    TopAppBar(title = {
        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
            Text(
                text = "Home Screen",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center
            )
        }

    })
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Column() {
            Text(text = FlashcardAppRoutes.Electricity.name, modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                navController.navigate(
                    FlashcardAppRoutes.Electricity.name
                )
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The activity gets re-created when the orientation changes that means the onCreate() function will be called once again and all the data saved in the activity class would be lost. To save the data through configuration changes we must save the data inside a ViewModel and collect the data from that ViewModel into our activity.
[Refer here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

Comment: Hi thanks for replying, but I am using a viewModel in my code and this still happens.

Comment: @AllenJMathew does it happen in all the devices or just in one?

Comment: When I tried it on the emulator this doesn't happen. Not sure if it is a problem with my physical device. Other apps, don't have this problem on my physical device.